# GCC 4.9.2 / GCC 4.8.1 - std::condition_variable::wait_until(...) bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have a problem with the method wait_until on c++11 conditional variables. It looks like the method return std::cv_status::no_timeout even if there are no notifications. The code below shows the problem.

There are comments in the code below illustrating the problem.

Compiler used: gcc 4.9.2 (on arch linux) 
               gcc 4.8.1 (on ubuntu 14.04)

I am greatful for any help i can get to solve this.

Best regars,
Mats

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>


std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable v;

void test_wait_until(int ms)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);

    std::cout << ms << "ms start\n";
    auto expires = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(ms);
    bool run = true;

    do
    {
        // This loop will run at 100% cpu time until
        // the timeout expires.

        auto status = v.wait_until(lock, expires);

        if(status == std::cv_status::timeout){
            std::cout << ms << "ms expired\n";
            run=false;
        }

        if(status == std::cv_status::no_timeout){
            // If the commend below is removed the
            // termial will be filled by the printout.
            // until the timeout expires.

            //std::cout << ms << "ms did not expire\n";
        }
    }while(run);
}


int main()
{
    test_wait_until(20000);
    test_wait_until( 5000);
    test_wait_until(  100);
    test_wait_until(  100);
    test_wait_until(   10);
    test_wait_until(    0);
    test_wait_until(   -10);
    test_wait_until(  -100);
    test_wait_until(  -100);
    test_wait_until( -5000);
    test_wait_until(-20000);
}
```

Comment: I would guess this is due to spurious wakeups. The documentation for `std::cv_status` for `no_timeout` dictates "the condition variable was awakened with notify_all, notify_one, or spuriously"

Comment: The loop runs as fast as it can (100% cpu).

Comment: Also, is this the only thread running? Perhaps this is an underlying cause for abnormal amounts of spurious wakeups.

Comment: [Can't reproduce on GCC 5.1 with the future expiry times](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3e2bfaa564b6f82), [nor the past ones](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/409e077aed073a39).

Comment: Yes there are only one thread in the program. The CPU is normally barely loaded ( < 4% ), but when the program runs and is in the loop the program uses 100% of that CPU core.

Comment: If GCC 5.1 runs it ok, it must be a bug in older versions. I have to try that.

Comment: Couldn't find anything relevant on Bugzilla.

Comment: clang 3.6 seems to have no worries either (Apple OSX 10.10.3). Everything looks normal. So at least you have options.

Comment: @sird The non-printing version is dealing with spirious wakeups (by looping) reasonably.  It taking 100% cpu is a poor QoI.  @ mlom: Have you seen this happen in non-toy code?  You have a mutex that cannot be shared, a loop that does nothing unless that mutex is shared (and waiting is optional): I cpuld see an optimizer going nuts.  What are your build flags (all of them)?  I am curious how bad the bug is.

Comment: Yes it was in real production code. The code example above is a example of how to reproduce the behavior. The compiler flag -pthread was missing. That means that at least  the  c++11 thread library starts acting funny at some places. As I understand it the -pthread flag affects how the code is compiled.  After adding the -pthread flag both the "toy" code and the production code behaves as it should. 0% cpu wile waiting for the time to expire.

Comment: The build flags when the loop takes 100%:  `g++ -std=c++11  t.cpp  -o test`

Comment: The build flags when the loop takes 0%:  `g++ -std=c++11  -pthread    t.cpp  -o test`

Comment: How did you intend to use condition variables without threading?

Comment: Ofcourse there are threads in the real code. The code above is reduced to show the behavior with as little code as possible. Anyway the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to build your executable with threading support. On Linux with gcc 4.9.2 this would go something like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -pthread
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok the problem was: 
I / we were using the -lpthread option instead of  the -pthread option for gcc.

The strange this is other things works rather well, but this seams to the solution.

Thank you all!

Comment: It is proper etiquette to accept an answer that may have been helpful. @lierdakil answer seemed to be correct. Glad you got your problem solved!

Comment: Sorry this is my first post to this forum. I dont see any option to accept the answer..

Comment: Thanks! As usual too easy :-)