# condition_variable::wait_until passes through unexpectedly g++ (9.4.0)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, pthreads

I am trying to understand the behaviour of [`condition_variable::wait_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable). I have two pieces of code which I expect will wait one second and then exit. However, when I execute the programs (compiled with g++ 9.4.0, libc6 2.3.2) the first does not wait at all, whereas the second example does.

(*see Update below for how to get correct behaviour in both examples*)

Here's the first example which does not wait (unlike what I would expect) when executed:

```cpp
// foo_passes_thru.cpp
// I compiled with `g++ foo_passes_thru.cpp`
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    const auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cv.wait_until(lk, now + 1000ms);

    return 0;

}
```

And the second example, which, when executed, does wait as expected:

```cpp
// foo_waits_1sec.cpp
// I compiled with `g++ foo_waits_1sec.cpp -lpthread`
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex m;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    std::thread causes_wait([]{});
    // don't even need the thread to run
    causes_wait.join();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    const auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cv.wait_until(lk, now + 1000ms);

    return 0;

}
```

- There does not appear to be a difference in the compiled `wait_until`.
- In both programs, there is ultimately a call to [`pthread_cond_timedwait`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_timedwait).

I am not sure if this is a case of *unspecified behaviour* or there is something incorrect in g++/STL/pthread. The documentation for `pthread_cond_timedwait` didn't suggest to me that there should be differences in behaviour.

### Update

Upon posting, a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145605/gcc-4-9-2-gcc-4-8-1-stdcondition-variablewait-until-bug) came up that I hadn't yet seen. The behaviour that I expect is restored for the first example if I add the [`-pthread`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/g++.1.html) compiler option. This option should be used to build both.

Comment: If anyone can explain why the `-pthread` command causes different behaviour to, say, `-lpthread` (which I had also tried with the first example) - that'd be nice. I wonder if - without `-pthread` - the call to `pthread_cond_timedwait` routes to some kind of stub?

Answer (score 2):

`wait_until` is allowed to wake up spuriously. There is no guarantee that it will wait until the specified time. You need to call `wait_until` in a loop, check the return value to determine whether a timeout occurred and you need some condition to check in order to decide whether the non-timeout wakeup was spurious. Alternatively you can use the second overload of `wait_until` that takes the condition as a predicate and implements the loop.

Without the `-pthread` option the program is single-threaded and a corresponding implementation is probably being used. In that implementation there can never be a non-spurious wakeup, so I think it is not surprising that it would be implemented to return immediately, although I have not checked the sources (of glibc or whichever libc implementation you use).

Comment: The spurious wakeup reads more like a corner case to me as opposed to 'expected' behaviour. What I think is happening is that without `-pthread`, a stub for `pthread_cond_timedwait` is used (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21104052/7050789 and https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/htl/forward.c.html) which returns immediately.

Comment: I agree with your suggestion that you should check if a timeout occurred; as this is (as you say) not guaranteed.

Comment: @stephematician My point is that simply returning immediately seems like a conforming implementation and one that makes sense for a single-threaded program in which there can't be any external change of the condition, so that it must be true initially. (Although I am not sure that there shouldn't be a clock check for timeout in the stub for actual conformance. In any case, it is not useful in a single-threaded program.)